# how to use Pi-cam module as webcam

Tags: webcam, raspicam

I have a Pi-Cam module for my raspberry pi and I want to make it behave like a webcam. Something Google could use for video chatting. Is there a driver I could download or do I have to make one myself? And if I have to make one, how do I go about it?

I have the raspberry pi model b+ running Raspian "Wheezy" if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make your own video chat using Voip ..

Using ffmpeg..

have a look on this also  http://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/python-picamera-setup/
and this also

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=45368

it will be fun to make this.

Comment: Seems like an interesting project. But would it be possible to make it cross-platform?

Comment: yes it is possible. you can do it..